# Problems regarding reading music

Tags: piano, sheet-music, sight-reading

I am self learning music(Piano) right now from various sources:

- Youtube
- Books (John Schaum mainly)
  I am having trouble in reading sheets a few times. How would you recommend me to go about it? Any good book with pieces of increasing difficulty, or book explaining sheet music in detail (Books cover theory in a nice way though)
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.   It's no different from asking "how can I learn to read a new language?"

Comment: There have been many questions regarding sight-reading on this site. Suggest you dig them out, and read their answers. Also, the oft recommended find a teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Self-learning to read music can be broken down into steps and approached much the same way as when you first learned to read and write your native language. The first thing I learned was the alphabet (notes) which I learned to recognize and write at the same time. Writing the notes helps a lot when it comes time to read notes. The next step came when I learned to read words (chords) and writing the words helped me recognize them more quickly when I needed to read them. Then I learned to read and write sentences (songs) which involved more writing and reading. After I could read and write sentences, I had to learn punctuation (symbols of expression) and develop a sense of rhythm (timing) to be able to recite (perform) the piece that I was reading in a fluent and somewhat polished fashion. In my case, this whole process took about the first and second grade of elementary school, and I still had to study even more as I grew older. The point that I wish to make is that this is a process, which is achievable if you have the determination and drive, but you'll have to do a lot of study and writing those notes, whether copying a song or trying to actually compose something yourself, will help tremendously when it comes time to sight-read sheet music. Sorry, I don't know any short cuts, except maybe finding a good teacher.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful and comprehensive response. The difference between reading language and reading music is in the execution of the mental translation. While the processes appear similar, reading music adds another layer of complexity in the execution of the written score where the conceptual pattern of the presentation requires its physical transformation and execution upon the target instrument. There is a tradition in European tutelage of learning to sing the notes while playing them on the instrument. To summarize skinny peacock: determination, drive, study, no short cuts.

Answer (score 0):

My advice in all these related questions is **reading by writing**: copy the notes in a system with a bigger line-distance so that you can write the letters (note-names) on the lines and between the lines right in the note-heads until you don’t need this transcription no longer:

https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=Reading+by+writing

Comment: There MUST be a better way! We look at the lines and spaces, translate what letter name that is, the try to find that letter name key on piano. Too many stages.

Comment: Of course, Tim. I had a girl at school, violinist, she looked at the notes and her fingers were finding the right tones, like a conditioned reflex. But she had no idea what this notes have been and what she played. The real way is the association of notes and keys, but we should know the names and identify the chords and analyze the music.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a book but a sight reading training software, creatively named Sight Reading Trainer.

It does just what you described: it lets you choose the difficulty level in terms of notes, speed, rhythmic elements, treble or bass clef, etc. and then you can either practice straight reading, play along, playing with the metronome, etc. and if you have a MIDI keyboard that plugs into the computer, the program will compare the notes you play with the score and show you exactly how close or how far you were. One limitation of this program is that it's a general purpose melodic lines trainer, for all instruments, and not a two-hand trainer specifically for piano. So, at the most, you can practice left and right hand separately, with single note lines. But other than that, it does do what you ask.

Full disclosure: I worked on coding this program and handling user support afterwards, so I'm not neutral about it, but you can try the free version for yourself

http://www.micrologus.com/courses/sight_reading_method